Why do class names appear in my Doxygen namespaces list?
I'm working on sprucing up the generated documentation for a C++ library of mine, using doxygen (the master branch HEAD as of right now, v1.11.0). After generation, and looking at the Namespaces page, I see both proper namespaces I've defined, but also many class names. I looked through my doxygen.cfg, and could not find any setting which is likely to result in this behavior.
So...

Is this intentional behavior for some reason?
Can I avoid it?  Or perhaps, what might I be doing wrong which results in this behavior?

I would quote some of my code or the doxygen.cfg, but that's a whole lot of text, so - I've added links, plus feel free to ask for additional information as necessary.

Minimal reproducible example? Classes shouldn't appear there AFAIK

Example: https://doxygen.scummvm.org/namespaces.html

@LHLaurini : I'll try whittling things down into an MWE. I was assuming there might be an obvious cause for this.
